# Angular JQuery UI Draggable Copy Of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have a web design here that I'm trying to make a draggable UI in.

[image]

Basically the user should be able to click and drag any of the different types of questions over from the left to the right hand side.

I'm able to make the buttons draggable by doing this:

```
$(".ui-draggable").draggable({
    cancel: false
})
```

There are two problems with this, the first is that the buttons themselves move out of place:
[image]

The second is that the buttons are draggable but only within the div that houses them, so you can't actually drag them to the righthand side of the screen.

It seems that the solution for this is to instead add an on-click function to the button such that when you click the button you create a div that looks exactly like the button and you set its location to be right where the cursor is with a parent element of `body`.

I'm struggling to figure out the best way to do this though.

Here was my attempt with an `ng-click`:

```
$scope.questionClicked = (event) ->
    str = '<button id="question-box" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="rating">' + event.currentTarget.innerText + '</button>'

    $('body').append(str)

    $("#question-box").css({
      top: event.pageY,
      left: event.pageX
    }).toggle();

    $("#question-box").draggable({
        cancel: false,
    })

    return true
```

This would generate a button in the body, but it would place it at the bottom of the screen and it wouldn't really be visible at first without some scrolling and the like.

Any ideas on how to handle this or recommendations on how to implement? Basically the say `Single Selection` button should be frozen on the lefthand side, but when you click and drag it, you should be able to drag a copy of the button over to the righthand side.

Comment: You will want to use the `clone` option in the api so the originals don't move

Comment: Oh that's perfect! Any idea how I can make the clone inherit from body so I can drag it outside of it's current div?

Comment: Oh wait, there's an `appendTo: 'body'` option! Perfect! Want to toss that in as an answer and I'll accept?!

Comment: Don't forget to accept @KScandrett 's answer.  Also, that's an awful lot of DOM manipulation in a controller, which is an Angular antipattern.  I would recommend you bundle any plugins or other DOM manipulation into a directive-- otherwise it could become a difficult maintain down the line.

Comment: I'm brand spanking new to angular. What's a directive?

Comment: @TomHammond [Angular Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive): custom elements (or attributes) that encapsulate some markup and functionality.  They have a `link` function in their definition in which you can put DOM manipulations/listeners/etc.  Mastery of directives allows for much cleaner/organized Angular code, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the helper option [helper: "clone"](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper) to stop the original elements moving, and [appendTo: "body"](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo) to append to the document's body to move it outside the starting container.